# sqlite file does not appear till I close the database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a mobile application which scans the device for audio files and I am putting these files in a sqlite db.

Now, my strategy is I commit first 100 entries to the db and make them available for browsing and play and then when I have scanned the rest of the files , I commit the rest thousands of files at the end, thus completing the db.

But I found that after my first commit of 100 files, sqlite file is not generated till I make a second commit of remaining thousands of files and close the db.

Why the db file is not generated?

Comment: Code?Log? Please post

Comment: Can you verify if this issue is related to closing of db.

Comment: `sqlite file is not generated till I make a second commit` Try making a first commit of **1** file, then a second one of **99** files, then the rest to see if it's an issue regarding the first commit or the db closure.

Comment: Let me verify this issue if its with closing

Comment: No the issue seems not not to be with closing as I closed the DB after commiting 100 files and still no sqlite file. I am checking into this issue further. During this anytime, any suggestions into the problematic areas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can one confirm that a sqlite file is created as soon as `sqlite3_open` is executed? ( Though I have verified it by making a small dummy program with open statement , followed by an infinite loop). In my original program  I had an `sqlite3_open` statement and hence sqlite file should have been created there only.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are invoking proper "flush" of your output streams wherever they are needed. Also if you play with transactions all the stuff happens in memory until you do committing.
Close of course does the flushing for you.